# How to forward a port to a DHCP client?

Tags: port-forwarding, port, wifi-configuration

The following approach works for me. Say my local `ip` address is 192.168.1.136, I am able to open the port 63102 using the method illustrated in the following image.

[image: A port forwarding example for router WRT54G2]

My issue is, if I configure my laptop's wifi for the option `obtain ip address automatically` then my laptop will no longer be able to communicate through the port after I restart it. So I am stuck to the option of assigning a `static ip adress` (192.168.1.136 in this example). That's fine, but if I try to take my laptop to a friend's place, I have to change it back to `obtain ip address automatically`. This is getting a bit cumbersome. Therefore, I was wondering if there's a way around it, a way by which I can open a port for all the `ip`s in my router's settings.

**System details:**
OS: Windows XP SP3
Router: Linksys WRT54G2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is create a **DHCP Reservation**, which will let you keep the laptop on 'Obtain IP automatically' but still have a consistent IP address.

1. Go to the 'Basic Setup' tab and click the 'DHCP Reservation' button.

[image: DHCP Reservation button for Linksys routers]

2. In the window that pops up, find your laptop and click the 'Select' box.

[image: Reserving a client]

3. Click the 'Add Clients' button. It will add that client to the list below.

[image: Reserved clients]

The IP address listed for that client will always be applied to that client. Then forward the ports as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not have the button `DHCP reservation`. Can you give me some suggestion other than that? I have updated the firmware to the latest (Linksys WRT54G2 Firmware Version: 1.5.02). Still no luck.

Comment: Funny, searching for information on your Router model it appears that it does not support DHCP reservations. [See this question](http://superuser.com/questions/8574/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-with-a-linksys-wrt54g2) which may be able to help you.

Comment: For the record, I own a WRT160Nv2, which is what I used to generate those images. I picked it up for about $20 used on Amazon. You may look into either custom firmware for your device, or a new router.

Comment: Yeah... I think my hardware is the primary limitation (I am wary of using DD-WRT for this particular router owing to it's low performance). Since this answer is the closest to what I need, I am going to accept it.